# Update Join with Limit 50000?

Tags: mysql

How to update 50,000 rows only when using `update`?

I have tried:

```
UPDATE type4
 LEFT JOIN sup ON sup.number = type4.number
 SET type4.exported = 2
 WHERE batch in ('B4', 'B5') AND outcome = 'new' AND sup.number is null
LIMIT 50000
```

It would not work when using limit..

How can it be done using subquery with a limit?

Comment: maybe try where between?

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this could work.

```
AND WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 50000
```

assuming that the ID is `auto increment` and is not broken.

or do a

```
UPDATE, SELECT WHERE IN LIMIT
```

*but I think it doesn't work anymore if you are on 5.5*

---

check this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33fab/1)

**warning some kind of pseudo-code**

```
UPDATE type4
LEFT JOIN sup ON sup.number = type4.number
SET  type4.exported = 2
WHERE batch IN ('B4', 'B5') 
AND outcome = 'new' 
AND sup.number is null
AND type4.id IN (
     SELECT id FROM (
         SELECT id FROM type4
         LIMIT 50000
     ) temp
 );
```